# PANDAS reading extra column from txt file that doesn't exist

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Im trying to read a txt into python using pd.read.csv where the columns are separated by tabs. I want to read it as a csv.
When it reads the file it adds an extra column with no header full of NAN entries. How do I avoid it reading this extra non-existing column. Code looks like this:

```
data = pd.read_csv('Desktop/SciKit Projects/Task 1/Datasets/Skin_NonSkin.txt', sep = '\t')
```

DataSet looks like this:

```
 B    G   R  Target  
 74  85  123      1  
 73  84  122      1  
 75  81  112      1  
 ...
```

and it ends up being as read as this:

```
       B     G    R  Target  Unnamed: 4
 0     74   85  123       1         NaN
 1     73   84  122       1         NaN
 2     72   83  121       1         NaN
 3     70   81  119       1         NaN
```

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
pd.read_csv(filename, delim_whitespace=True, skipinitialspace=True)
```